# Grails Commons DBCP Pool vs. Tomcat JDBC Pool

Tags: grails, jdbc, grails-2.0

I found the [Tomcat JDBC Pool plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jdbc-pool) which replaces Grails Commons DBCP Pool with Tomcat JDBC Pool

1. Which one is better Grails Commons DBCP Pool or Tomcat JDBC Pool?
2. Are there different scenarios where one should use the one pool an the scenarios where one should use the other pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Commons DBCP pool is very good, but the Tomcat pool is more flexible and has higher performance. The initial blog posts from tomcatexpert.com are a bit dated, but should still be very relevant and if anything the numbers should be better now: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/tags/connection-pool

Note that in 2.3 we've [replaced Commons DBCP with Tomcat JDBC](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7455), so it makes sense to start using it now.

Comment: Do I have to set pool=true in my DataSource.groovy? What do I have to change? or is it just install the plugin and you are done?

Comment: Just install the plugin. It has a bean post-processor that automatically changes the class name for you. The cool thing is that the other config options are the same, so this is the only required change.

Comment: To clarify a little more, as of Grails 2.3 you don't need to install the plugin because the Tomcat pool is the default as of 2.3.

Comment: One Small confusion. The default connection pool configured in Tomcat 8 is DBCP2 and the default configured in grails 3.x is Tomcat JDBC. So Don't we need to use same pool in both?

Comment: No, if you're creating two different connection pools you can use whatever impl you want for each. If you want to use a JNDI pool configured in Tomcat (or whatever server you're deploying to) you wouldn't configure a local pool, just a DataSource that gets connections via JNDI. Creating a local pool would be redundant since the server's JNDI pool already handles allocating extra instances and making them available.